# JSON/Python get output from subcategories

Tags: python, json

New in JSON/Python... I'd like to select a part of sub category.
Here is a part of the JSON file:

```
  {
    "items": [{
        "seasonId": 59,
        "createdDate": "20200721T205735.000Z",
        "participants": [{
            "tag": "#8CJ89RJ",
            "name": "Cåmille",
            "cardsEarned": 1401,
            "battlesPlayed": 1,
            "wins": 1,
            "collectionDayBattlesPlayed": 3,
            "numberOfBattles": 1
        }, {
            "tag": "#Y2828CQ",
            "name": "<c2>MoutBrout",
            "cardsEarned": 1869,
            "battlesPlayed": 1,
            "wins": 1,
            "collectionDayBattlesPlayed": 3,
            "numberOfBattles": 1
        }, {
            "tag": "#2Q8CRC8RY",
            "name": "Desnoss",
            "cardsEarned": 2337,
            "battlesPlayed": 1,
            "wins": 0,
            "collectionDayBattlesPlayed": 3,
            "numberOfBattles": 1
        }, {
            "tag": "#80CGRR2CY",
            "name": "pixtango",
            "cardsEarned": 1402,
            "battlesPlayed": 1,
            "wins": 1,
            "collectionDayBattlesPlayed": 2,
            "numberOfBattles": 1
        }]
    }]
}
```

I would like a result as:
Camille - 1401 cards - 1 win
etc
However, my issue is that those infos are under items/0/participants.
I know how to do with data under one category. Here is an exemple for another JSON file and how I'd like the new one to be:

```py
for item in data ["items"][:5]:
    print("Name: %s\nTrophies: %s\nTag: %s\n\n" % (
                        item["name"],
                        item["trophies"],
                        item["tag"],
             ))
```

Any idea please ?

EDIT: I'm sorry, here is how it looks:
[image]

For exemple, I would like to print the 5 first names. I put this:

```
         for item in data ["items"][:5]:
                print (data[items][0][participants]['name'])
```

And I received this error:
NameError: name 'items' is not defined

Comment: Can i suggest to paste your json formatted/pretty printed it is much easier to understand.. and can you also add an clearer example of what you want to to get

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need something like this:

```
items_str = [f'Name: {i["name"]}\nTrophies: {i["trophies"]}\nTag: "{i["tag"]}' 
             for i in json_dict['items']]
for i in items_str:
    print(i)
```

sorry, it's not so easy to understand from your data

UPD: If there are many 'items' with 'participants' in each, this code should work for you:

```
participants = []
for item in json_dict['items']:
    for participant in item['participants']:
        p = 'Name: {}\nTrophies: {}\nTag: {}'.format(item["name"], item["trophies"], item["tag"])
        participants.append(p)
        print(p)
```

Comment: I modified the post and add more information, I hope this can help to help me ;)

Answer (score 0):

```py
    sub_dict = dict['items'][0]['participants']
    print("Name: {}\nTrophies: {}\nTag:{}\n\n".format(sub_dict['name'],sub_dict['trophies'],sub_dict['tag']))
```

For other participants increase the array index.

Comment: I modified the post, do you think your command is still ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the JSON data from the file and prints it.

```
import json
with open('j.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
for item in data['items']:
    for p in item['participants']:
        print p
        print("Name: %s\nTrophies: %s\nTag: %s\n\n" % (
                        p["name"],
                        p["trophies"],
                        p["tag"]))
```

Comment: i like the idea, however outputs will go to a file text...

Answer (score 0):

I think it may help you:

Code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
j='{"items":[{"seasonId":59,"createdDate":"20200721T205735.000Z","participants":[{"tag":"#8CJ89RJ","name":"Cåmille","cardsEarned":1401,"battlesPlayed":1,"wins":1,"collectionDayBattlesPlayed":3,"numberOfBattles":1},{"tag":"#Y2828CQ","name":"<c2>MoutBrout","cardsEarned":1869,"battlesPlayed":1,"wins":1,"collectionDayBattlesPlayed":3,"numberOfBattles":1},{"tag":"#2Q8CRC8RY","name":"Desnoss","cardsEarned":2337,"battlesPlayed":1,"wins":0,"collectionDayBattlesPlayed":3,"numberOfBattles":1},{"tag":"#80CGRR2CY","name":"pixtango","cardsEarned":1402,"battlesPlayed":1,"wins":1,"collectionDayBattlesPlayed":2,"numberOfBattles":1}]}]}'
y = json.loads(j)
y=pd.DataFrame([x for x in y['items'][0]['participants']])
print(y)
```

output:

[image]